# Why this condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dynamics-crm

Could someone explain what these conditions are checking for?  I understand it has to do with checking to see if other fields are already disabled, but I I am not completely clear on it.  What is referencing the getDisabled  method doing specifically?

```
if (!userHasRoleNeeded) {
            Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, i) {
                if (control && control.getDisabled && !control.getDisabled()) {
                    control.setDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a && b` will not execute `b` if `a` is "falsey". `control.getDisabled` is checking to see if `control.getDisabled` is "truthy" (if it exists), and if it does, it will execute the method. Without this check, if `control.getDisabled` did not exist, it would try to execute an undefined method and raise an execution error. *Why* this is done a choice by the library authors.

Further reading: https://j11y.io/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Comment: Are you saying that it is checking to see if the getDisabled function definition exists on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Basically we do this to avoid errors, when the `control.setDisabled(true);` snippet tries to disable controls like "iframe", "webresource" & "subgrid" as these control doesn't have `disabled` property.